# How to have a cornerradius on Flex 4 TextInput component

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

How do I get corner radius on my TextInput component in Flex 4.

```
<s:TextInput prompt="username" width="150" maxChars="100" id="txt_username"
    color="#000000"/>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Create a custom skin (possibly by copying spark TextInputSkin) and add a border graphic with rounded corners, like this:

```
<!-- border -->
<s:Rect id="border" left="0" right="0" top="0" bottom="0" 
        radiusX="10" radiusY="10">

    <s:stroke>
        <s:SolidColorStroke id="borderStroke" weight="1" />
    </s:stroke>
</s:Rect>
```

If you want more special rounded corners you can also use these attributes:

```
topLeftRadiusX="4" topLeftRadiusY="8" 
bottomLeftRadiusX="2" bottomRightRadiusY="10"
```

The default TextInputSkin does not allow for rounded corners, so there is no style that you could set on your TextInput to do it. So, no, there's no other way than creating a custom skin class.

Answer (score 3):

You could take it a step further and make it dynamic. Create a custom TextInputSkin based on spark TextInputSkin and in the updateDisplayList method add this code above the super.updateDisplayList() call.

In YourTextInputSkin.mxml,

```
// in updateDisplayList()
if (getStyle("cornerRadius")!==undefined) {
    border.radiusX = border.radiusY = getStyle("cornerRadius");
    background.radiusX = background.radiusY = getStyle("cornerRadius");
}
```

That's it. You're done!

Now to use it add a CSS class selector to add a cornerRadius style like so:

```
/* set the Textinput.styleName to this style */

s|TextInput.roundedInput
{
    contentBackgroundAlpha: .4;
    contentBackgroundColor: #000000;
    cornerRadius:           10;
    skinClass:              ClassReference("view.skins.TextInputRoundedSkin");  
}
```

And set your instance to the class,

```
<s:TextInput styleName="roundedInput"/>
```

Unfortunately, you can't set the cornerRadius style on TextInput component instance in MXML. *Should Flex support a styles tag for this type of thing like HTML tags do? Should styles declared in the Skin be proxied to the component using them? Currently the Flex compiler would throw an error if you declared a style in the Skin and tried to use it on the component instance even though it's valid to declare that style and any other style in the CSS. What about if UIComponents had a style proxy object that let you set styles?* Anyway, I digress.

If you want to make that style available on the TextInput instance in addition to the previous methods you can do that by extending TextInput and adding the cornerRadius style metadata to it. You can also set the skinClass (inline or in a defaults.css file in the library) while you're at it.

Something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:TextInput xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
             xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
             xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
             skinClass="TextInputRoundedSkin" >
    <fx:Metadata>
        [Style(name="cornerRadius", inherit="no", type="uint")]
    </fx:Metadata>
</s:TextInput>
```

To use,

```
<local:MyExtendedTextInput cornderRadius="8" />
```

In the future you won't have to declare the CSS.